# Is asking to write a letter on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I need to write a letter to some one properly. Can I ask it as question to write letter for me by saying all requirements.

Is it allowed to ask to write a formal letter for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking what to write is off-topic, and asking other people to write something for you is also off-topic. You might possibly find help in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168) if you are looking for advice revising a letter that you wrote yourself, provided that you have specific questions and don't expect people to do the work for you.

Comment: That said, we've gotten questions *about writing* email (not about *what to write* in the email), so email itself seems to be in-scope.  But Writers is not a writing service.